# RoR user management & dictionary tutorial recommendations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I haven't touched ROR in close to 4 years.

I have an idea for an app that will rely on user input to build a dictionary, and other users can add to the dictionary - basically a wiki.

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial out there for get my head around creating user models, authentication and other basic stuff.

Also I read that rails 3.2 makes user authentication much more simple and stable. Sound right?

I'm on a mac running 10.7 and i have Xcode 4.3.2 and text mate - if any of that is useful info.

Thanks guys!

Adam

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848427/rails-book-suggestions/9848479#9848479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really liked this railscast, you might too

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch